# Pagination links for result pages too far down on last page

Tags: support, search, usability

I'm looking at questions that have a particular tag attached to them. There are two pages worth, with very few on the second page of results.

The links to other results pages are nowhere near the list of questions on that page.

Instead, because there are so few on the last page, the links are way down at the bottom of the page.

See [this search on the <kbd>spatial</kbd> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=spatial&page=2&sort=newest&pagesize=30) on SO, for instance.

Answer (score -1):

This will probably be tagged, <kbd>status-bydesign</kbd> as it's just the way it's showing up on the fetched results. The footer is below the other elements of the page, no matter how long or short it comes before.

If you didn't want that last page to be so lonely, you could try and change the number of returned results per page. Maybe 15 per page will spread them out better. Or see if 50 will contain it all.

Its appearance on a shortened results page also depends on how many tags you have marked as interesting/ignore. The more you have, the further down the footer is pushed and subsequently, the higher the chances of lots of whitespace between the last listed question in a search and the footer.

Comment: Also, this issue only affects webkit.

Comment: Seen it on Opera though.

Comment: If this is "by design", then the design is problematic. I'm not complaining that some answers are 'lonely', I'm complaining that the page links are way the hell out of the way on a mostly-empty last page of results, regardless of the size of a page.

Also, I observed this in Firefox 3.0, not some Webkit-based browser or Opera.

Comment: Comments here say that it's not just your browser alone and that it's a design of how the page is marked up. The pagination section clears itself at the bottom of the main content of the page, so if you have a lot of watched tags, that will push the paging section further down.